# When exactly does the Guzzle 6 promise resolve?

Tags: php, guzzle

We're working on a Guzzle 6 based PHP client for a response time sensible case.

Guzzle can do [async requests via curl](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#async-requests) that return a promise API. Because the body can be retrieved as a stream I'm wondering whether the promise resolves (e.g. forced via wait())

a) when the last header is received (like the [on_headers hook](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-headers))?

b) when the body has been fully received?

I tried to find out in the Guzzle sources, but I failed miserably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **option b**

If you're using the default Curl-based calls, the promises don't resolve until after the curl calls are complete. In CurlHandler's `__invoke`:

```
curl_exec($easy->handle);
...
return CurlFactory::finish($this, $easy, $this->factory);
```

which returns:

```
return new FulfilledPromise($easy->response);
```

Similar code exists for CurlMultiHandler. The promises aren't resolved in the `on_headers` functions, so presumably it's when the body is complete. I believe the streams are actually memory/disk-based, not network-based.

And if you think about it, this makes sense; you shouldn't successfully resolve a promise before you know all the data downloaded OK.